# Typescript Generics "not assignable" error

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create what I thought was a fairly simple structure for an object that is assignable to specific key names, but typescript is giving me an error that I can't make sense of.

```js
    type Drawing = {
        date: string,
        draw_time: string,
        winning_numbers: string
    }

    type Winner<GameNames> = {
        [Property in keyof GameNames]: Drawing[]
    }

    const gameNames = {
        name3: 'cash3',
        name4: 'cash4',
    } as const
    
    type GameNames = (typeof gameNames)[keyof typeof gameNames]
    
    const { name3, name4 } = gameNames

    const winners: Winner<GameNames> = {
        [name3]: [] as Drawing[],
        [name4]: [] as Drawing[],
    }
```

It's giving me this error: `Type '{ cash3: Drawing[]; cash4: Drawing[]; }' is not assignable to type 'Winner<GameNames>'.` ... except it is, right?  I've even asked copilot and chatgpt for some insight, they both said (in a nutshell) "It looks good to me."

[Typescript Playground Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIgTgQwO4EsB2BzKBeKBvAKCmKgBMFgIAuKAZ2DnQwBoiTTEkB9YFAW2p0GTViSio0aJlzQBXPgCMIcWjXqNMBAL4ECoSFADq6NMoA8AcQQCActYi0AfDnxtiAbQAKcAPaQ4oFDoUADWECA+AGZQVrb2tAC6NPDITO4J2roAxj5o9FAY9nYCtC6EYmj2AMw0AORZCLQAFlW1oiSVAgAsdQ3NXW3aUI1QOXnAbHrg0LEQxQ4uABT6EFEFRfEAlO5hEdEra4VxJRnEBGP5eFCdEFXM1-ZdUFouR3Px2bn5EqYqNMaScyzeZOMpuKDuG5VJIQhLDUopCQYdLtDw3Low9Lw2CcNIJVhaIA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Record` type to create an object type:

```
type Winner<GameNames extends string> = Record<GameNames, Drawing[]>
```

[test it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIgTgQwO4EsB2BzKBeKBvAKCmKgBMFgIAuKAZ2DnQwBoiTTEkB9YFAW2p0GTViSio0aJlzQBXPgCMIcWjXqNMBAL4ECoSFADq6NMoA8AcQQCActYi0oEAB6U0pR%20qYA%20HFABKEADGAPZwpJb2dgK0zLCcTADaALreuqFo9FAYUfaOuIRiaPYAzDQA5EEItAAWJeWiJMUCACwVVbUtDdpQ1VAZ9Gx64NBWtnl%20ABT6ECEAZtm5MQCUiQDWECDzUDPbOeMxyUMDwPhQzRAlcRctUFp%20%20xDRDukhmacSpio0xpLmY088r4CmxiIkLiVkjQUr1HPBkElko0wTcoVAYX14RIMClWFogA)

Your method also works but without `keyof``

```
type Winner<GameNames> = {
    [Property in GameNames as string]: Drawing[]
}
```

[test it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIgTgQwO4EsB2BzKBeKBvAKCmKgBMFgIAuKAZ2DnQwBoiTTEkB9YFAW2p0GTViSio0aJlzQBXPgCMIcWjXqNMBAL4ECoSFADq6NMoA8AcQQCActYi0AfDnxtiAbQAKcAPaQ4oFDoUFa29rRQCBHqTAC6NPDITO6x2roAxj5o9FAY9nYCEbiEYmj2AMw0AOTpUQAW5VWiJGUCACzVtbR1bU3akRGZ2cBseuDQoRAFDi4AFPoQPgBmufnhAJTuANYQIMtQC-t5YYWpxARDOXhQrRDlzDf2bVBaLsdT4RlZORKmKjTGSTmSbTJwuEokdy3crxKApAawTjJWLNDy3Nqw%20FRRFJTApVhaIA)

Comment: Why is that? Are literal strings not allowed as keys?

Comment: Nevermind, I think I get it. Since literals are their own types, Record can't know if the string passed in works so you have to cast it. This makes sense. Thank you!